# How does adding LIMIT work with Where conditions in mysql?

Tags: mysql, where, limits

In my database, there is only one record which satisfies the condition **iv_title = 'ball skills'**.
Now I'm executing the following query :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `imageAndVideo`
WHERE
    `iv_title` = 'ball skills' AND `iv_file_type` = 2
ORDER BY
    `iv_create`
DESC
LIMIT 1, 6
```

This above query doesn't output any record, I don't know why? Can somebody please explain this to me?
If I execute the below (removing LIMIT) query I get the desired limit.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `imageAndVideo`
WHERE
    `iv_title` = 'ball skills' AND `iv_file_type` = 2
ORDER BY
    `iv_create`
DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LIMIT 1, 6` is short for `LIMIT 6 OFFSET 1`, [in MySQL parlance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). `OFFSET` means *skip this many records* from the start of the result set. So what you're saying is, give me 6 records after skipping 1 (records 2 through 7, starting at 1). With only 1 record, and skipping that 1, you have no results.